# nginx alias and proxy_pass on the same location

Tags: nginx

I want to be able to do 2 actions on the same location:

1) if the user is logged in (a cookie is not set)
 do a `alias`. This will display a landing page

2) if he's logged in do a `proxy_pass` to the app web server. 
However I get

```
"alias" directive is not allowed here in ...
```

when I'm trying to do either `proxy_pass` or `alias` inside an if. How can I do it without rewriting to a new location?

Here is my config:

```
location / {
                set $logged_in "false";
                if ($cookie_mojolicious) {
                        set $logged_in "true";
                }
                if ($logged_in = "false") {
                        # rewrite ^/$ /landing last;
                        alias /var/www/S7012MY/main_landing/;
                        last;
                }
                proxy_pass http://test;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
```

Comment: It's not recommended https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/